# How to access sda4 device/directory?

Tags: files

Our camera DVR is not recording anymore. The disk is full and the vendor has not been helpful in freeing up space. I am trying to figure out why the primary disk is full.

I've tried accessing it through `cd /mnt/dev/sda4`, but as you may have guessed, that did not work. Also, there is no GUI enabled for this device. When trying to `startx`, I get

```
X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting.
```

How can I get access to the `/dev/sda4` directory (or device) to see what's eating my space? And after doing so, how can I pull up directory/file space without having to wait so long for the du command to compute?

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        65G   20G   42G  32% /
udev            7.9G   12K  7.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  300K  3.2G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.9G   84K  7.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda3        26G  5.0G   20G  21% /storage
tmpfs           3.0M  176K  2.9M   6% /tmp/tmpfs
/dev/sdb1       7.5G  5.5G  2.1G  74% /media/cfrestore
/dev/sda4       3.5T  3.4T     0 100% /mnt
/dev/sdc        3.6T  309M  3.4T   1% /media/4fc55b9f-e2cd-4c88-a1d0-5a94ac81dce4
```

My system:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS"
```

Comment: It should be `cd /mnt`, actually, there's no `/mnt/dev/sda4`. Mind that you might need sudo to delete there anything, it might be mounted by root and you wont have read/write permissions

Comment: Well, I have full access to the device with the "admin" password. How would I go about exploring the sda4 partition?

Comment: You could use ls command for listing files, but as I see from your comment on the answer bellow, you didnt find anything in `/mnt` folder, right ? How about `ls -al` ? this should list hidden files, if there are any. Among other things, there is `mc` which is midnight commander (not installed by default), which is a file manager for command line. Also, why you do not have GUI ? You've uninstalled it ? As for startx, i dont think regular users can run it, only root

Comment: I'll give the `ls -al` a try in a few. As for the GUI, I cannot say. It is a vendor-provided DVR, so I don't know the exact configuration. Their support hasn't been helpful in various aspects. I'll try installing `mc` as well. I'll update in a bit.

Comment: Try `sudo startx` for starting X server and execute `cd /mnt && ls -al` to view all files inside the device, then you may use `rm -r file_name1 file_name2` etc for removing required files.

Comment: Well, if this is vendor-provided DVR, maybe it is locked or read/write protected in some way ?

Comment: Tried installing `mc` and received this error: <br> sudo apt-get install mc<br> 
Reading package lists... Done<br> 
Building dependency tree<br> 
Reading state information... Done<br> 
E: Unable to locate package mc<br> 
<br/>whenever I do ls -al in the mnt directory all I get is this: <br/>    nlss@nlss-GW4000-00012e4bb2a1:/mnt$ ls -al
    total 28
    drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Oct  1  2013 .
    drwxr-xr-x 25 root root  4096 Mar 31 13:00 ..
    drwxrwxrwx  9 nlss nlss  4096 Jan 14 20:54 local
    drwx------  2 root root 16384 Oct  1  2013 lost+found

Comment: @mikerdz: Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) are much better readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Although I feel, that you should rather open a new follow-up question, because this one is about finding the right mount point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device currently is mounted on `/mnt`. That's what the bold line in the output of (probably) `df -h` says. So just open your file browser and go to the root. In Nautilus (the standard file browser of Ubuntu) just click on "Computer" in the navigation on the right. Then open the folder `mnt`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't start a file browser as we do not have a GUI. I'm pretty good with a GUI, however, it's the CLI that kills me. And, yes that was from the `df -h` output. I added the emphasis myself.

Comment: `cd /mnt` to switch to the right location, then you can work on the command line. For example `ls -l` will list all files and folders.

Comment: here's the output for the `ls -l` command: brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,   4 Mar 31 10:14 sda4

Comment: What's your current location? This lists a file which is named "sda4". If you go to /mnt with `cd /mnt` `ls -l` will list you all files and folders in the file system of the partition /dev/sda4 and you can remove files with `rm filename` from there.

Comment: your original post reply was the answer I needed. The device is mounted and accessible through /mnt. I thought you had to do something to mount change the partitions. Rusty Linux... Thanks again for everyone's help. I was able to remove the security settings from these files (gotta love Google) and delete the unnecessary files. This cleared up a few hundred GB. Thanks again.